# Layout management inside Cairo DrawingArea/Context?

Tags: layout, mono, monodevelop, cairo, gtk#

I have a window in mono gtk#, which has lot of VBoxes & HBoxes. These boxes contain some buttons, labels, and some other widgets also. Now I need to make this window alone to transparent.
I created one drawingArea by referring [zetcode page](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/drawing/).

But inside this drawing area I'm not able to do the arrangements of my widgets, one Move function is available, but it is not much use for me. So how do I do widget arrangement neatly inside a drawingArea?

Comment: Do you mean you want the window to be transparent and the widgets on it to be visible?

Comment: @muszeo yes, that's what I want.